# Flask app not return any response when raising error (python)

Tags: python, json, flask

I am building a Flask API in Python. When a function inside the API throws an error, the server does not return any response. I have tried using try-except blocks and print statements to debug the issue, but I am still unable to resolve it.

Here is some relevant code:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, Response, request, jsonify
def first_function():
  try:
    second_function()
  except Exception as error:
    error_message = str(error).split("\n")[0]
    raise ValueError(error_message)

def second_function():
  try:
    print("second_function")
    third_function()
    print("I do not want to see this sentence.")
  except Exception as error:
    error_message = str(error).split("\n")[0]
    raise ValueError(error_message)

def third_function():
  try:
    print("third_function")
    print(1/0)
  except Exception as error:
    error_message = str(error).split("\n")[0]
    raise ValueError(error_message)

@app.route('/control', methods=['POST'])
def get():
  response = ''
  try:
    first_function()
    return jsonify(response)
  except Exception as error:
    error_message = str(error).split("\n")[0]
    response = {"text" : "Something went wrong when operating 'get' process. -> " + str(error_message)}
    print("Error on main function ", error_message)
    return jsonify(response)
```

After that i want to see division error message on response.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I cannot duplicate this. I see the message.  HOWEVER, I am using postman to do a POST to the endpoint per your `methods=['POST']` but I see your message indicates you are potentially expecting a `"get"`. Perhaps you mean to use `methods=['GET']`.  Note if I make that change and do a get, I still see the expected message returned.

Comment: @JonSG that is not the problem but thank you

Comment: Not sure how to help then. using your exact code I get your expected response.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case where you would want to use the flask abort funtion.This raises an httpexception.

```
    from flask import abort
    @app.route('/control', methods=['POST'])
    def get():
      response = ''
      try:
        first_function()
        return jsonify(response)
      except Exception as error:
        error_message = str(error).split("\n")[0]
        response = {"text" : "Something went wrong when operating 'get' process. -> " + str(error_message)}
        print("Error on main function ", error_message)
        abort(400, error_message)
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: Nothing changed, if i do request, it doesnt return anything and gives timeout error after a while

Comment: Can it be that you need to restart you API after you made the changes. Because with your attempt I indeed got this:
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000 after 2033 ms: Couldn't connect to server
But with my changes I get:
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>division by zero</p>

Which is what you want right?